# Copy excel Picture to different tab using IF THEN formula

Tags: excel, vba, image, if-statement, excel-formula

I've created an order flow in excel with conditional formatting. The conditional formatting shows the manager the timeline of an order based off of the start date and end date. I've inserted pictures on a separate sheet (sheet2) in the excel file that I would like to overlay on the timeline start date to give the viewer a visual of what product was ordered and how many days (start - end) it will take to arrive.

**Is there a way to use a formula within the cells on the order flow to pull back the pictures from Sheet2?** The formula I currently have references the picture but the picture pulls back "0" into the cell on Sheet1.

I also created VBA to copy the picture from sheet2 to sheet1 but I'm having a really tough time getting it to paste to the correct cell. That route might be a dead end.

Current formula:

=IF(AND(F6=I6,H6=Sheet2!$B$11,Picture1,"NA"))

Current table without pictures:
[image]
What I would like to accomplish with formulas or macros:

[image]

Here's what sheet2 looks like for reference:
[image]

Comment: i assume you want the images at the cell that indicates the start of a process? And when would you like the list to be updated? when you add a new line with a text matching your list of images or when the starting point of the process is defined?

also, is this list being updated a lot or do you have a complete list where you want to add the images?

Comment: Yes, if I could get the image to go at the first order day that would be great. Otherwise, anywhere within the work order length would suffice. I have VBA in this worksheet that's going to pull order request data from SharePoint. The Macro will clear all current data and then repopulate all of the work orders (add new and remove any that were canceled). If there is a formula that I can use in these cells to pull back the relevant pictures I can add that to the VBA code.. I just don't know what process, code or formula I need to move these pictures to the beginning dates.

Comment: I answered your question without answering your question. The list could be updated several times a day or once a week. Hard to tell.

Comment: I am afraid that the question did not mean what you understood... The question (I think) wants meaning **what to trigger** the picture copying procedure. Excel has some events which can be used to automate the process. So when would you like to start the  copying process and where, related to the modified cell position, to be it/them pasted? Is it clear enough what is to be supplied in terms of necessary information? We need to know based on what to start the copying process and where **exactly** the picture(s) to be placed and based on what to know **whitch picture to be copied**...

Comment: @BrandonM. since you're using vba anyway to populate your excel i would suggest using vba code to pull the images when you're pulling the data from th sharepoint instead of using a formula. Should give you more controllability over when and what should be copied, in your case the images. Can you maybe show the code you use for importing the data, that would make it easier on helping you to find out where to adjust your vba code. **keep in mind not to publish any sensitive data**

Comment: @FaneDuru I would like the formula to be entered into every cell within the order flow table (I6 down and right). Once I have a working formula I can insert it into the VBA.

Comment: What to "insert into the VBA"? If I understand that you need the picture to be brought **after the formula has been input in a specific cell inside to "the order flow table"** would it be a correct understanding? Even if so, you need to explain **based on what a specific picture to be chosen**? Do they have relevant names? Based on what to link the respective picture names from the cell where it must be brought? What address does "the order flow table" have? Should the picture be placed **on the cell receiving a formula**?

Comment: Should THE PICTURE be placed somewhere else, but related to the modified cell position? Should the copying process should be triggered by the formula you mention copying in a specific cell, or **by the respective cell value is changed BY THAT FORMULA**?

Comment: Do you really need help, no offence?

Comment: Excel 365 has the [IMAGE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-function-7e112975-5e52-4f2a-b9da-1d913d51f5d5?ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) function you could use something like `=IF(AND(F6=I6,H6=Sheet2!$B$11),IMAGE("<URL To Image>"),"NA")`

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, the picture needs to move with the time range (Start-End) specified in the cells to the left. Darren Bartrup-Cook that formula works perfectly for what I need thank you!